# Core Data: Initialise persisent store with a bundled database

Tags: ios, core-data

My iOS app embed a .sqlite database containing a list of cities with postal codes and geolocation informations.

I initialize my Core Data stack like this:

```
- (void)initializeCoreData {
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"cities" withExtension:@"momd"];
NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
NSAssert(mom != nil, @"Error initializing Managed Object Model");

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:mom];
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
[moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:psc];
[self setManagedObjectContext:moc];
NSURL *storeURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"cities" withExtension:@"sqlite"];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[self managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator];
    NSDictionary * options = @{NSSQLitePragmasOption:@{@"journal_mode":@"DELETE"}};
    NSPersistentStore *store = [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error];
    NSAssert(store != nil, @"Error initializing PSC: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
});
```

}

As you can see, I don't copy the database to the application directory, but read it directly from the application bundle.

I only have to read this database, so is it safe to initialise Core Data like i do, or should I copy the database to the application directory before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is safe but I would add the "read-only" option as well so that you can protect yourself from potential mistakes:

```
NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
options[NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption] = @YES;
options[NSSQLitePragmasOption] = @{@"journal_mode":@"DELETE"};
```